# JAVA - MySQL an ArrayList

Tags: java, mysql, arraylist

I have query from MySQl

```
String sqlSearch = "SELECT * from Item"
```

and method with ArrayList

```
  public static ArrayList<String> checkNo() throws SQLException {

    ArrayList<String> no= new ArrayList<String>();

    DbManager db = new DbManager();
    db.connect();
    String sql = "SELECT * from Category where id = " + idUser + " ";

    Statement stmt = db.connect().createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    while (rs.next()) {

        no.add(rs.getString("nameCategory"));

    }
    db.disconnect();
    return no;
}
```

And I get from specific user his category in arraylist, but how to pass this category to sqlSearch???

```
  SELECT * from Item where category ????
  data from ArrayList
```

Any idea?

Comment: Using prepared statements is recommended. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could loop through the `ArrayList` items and build a `String` to use in the `where` clause like this

```
String inCondition = "";
boolean first = true;
ArrayList<String> categories = checkNo();

for(String cat : categories){
    if(first){
        first = false;
    } else {
        inCondition += ",";
    }
    inCondition += cat;
}

String sqlSearch = "SELECT * from Item where category in (" + inCondition + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `checkNo()` method return an ArrayList. It looks like this ArrayList will have only one item, get that item from the ArrayList and pass it to the query like this.

```
String category = list.get(i);    
"Select * from Item where category = "+category;
```

Comment: The assumption that the category will be only one is a bit strong, with such few information about the tables involved... isn't it?

Comment: I made that assumption thinking that the above query will return only 1 result because of where clause matching with 'id'

Answer (score 0):

As your query is not clear am giving you a sample code,jus try it

```
if (count > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            ColumnName= no.get(i).getColumnName();
            }
        getItemQuery = "FROM Item where category in (" +ColumnName + ")";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this,

one way is two combine two queries:

```
SELECT * from Item where category in (SELECT nameCategory from Category where id = idUser )
```

as suggested its better to use prepared statement.